# Laravel 10 Raw Query and backtick issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-10

i have this code from a project that i am working on and i am actually upgrade a Laravel Project to Laravel version 10. In project on small portions i use DB:raw(...) and since there is a change into Framework regard this: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#raw-expressions i need to adjust my code and make it work:

```
$query = Transaction::query();
$query
            
->where(['funds_account_id' => $fundsAccount->id])

            
->withSum(['transactionItems as incR' => function ($query){
                $query->whereNotNull('completed_at'); 
                $query->where('void', 0);
            }], 'increase_amt')


            
->withSum(['transactionItems as decR' => function($query){
                $query->where('void', 0);
            }], 'decrease_amt')

            
->selectRaw(DB::raw('@balance := @balance + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(incR - decR),0)) AS theBalance')->getValue(DB::connection()->getQueryGrammar()))
            
->from('transactions, (SELECT @balance := 0) AS variableInit')
            
->with(['user', 'Type'])
            
->whereNotNull('completed_at')
            
->orderBy('completed_at');

$results = $query->get();
```

So i am having issue with backticks as i mentioned above and i get this error

[Error i got in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK7t0.png)

As pointed out, i have the backtick in wrong place i want to be near "transactions`  <-- here "

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Ahh yes the old Termination and Validation issue.  Well MySQL uses '' and "" to indicate strings, and uses ` for like column names.  Passing from the front end of php to the backend of MySQL requires character validation, which you are going to want to do anyways to avoid MySQL Injection attacks, if you have any ambition of allowing randos on the internet to touch it.

Comment: Oh wait i just re-looked at that picture .. is this SQL and not MYSQL ?

Comment: Using comma joins isn't really good practice anymore. That said, this doesn't have anything to do with your current raw statements, but rather your `from` clause. It's treating the whole `from` clause as a table name, so you'll need to separate them out, or use a DB::raw in the from statement

Comment: (Though why you have `(SELECT @balance := 0) AS variableInit` in a `from` clause, I have no idea....)

Comment: @aynber if i do not set `(SELECT @balance := 0) AS variableInit` in a `form` i get null for `balance` into the result in browser

Comment: Try `DB::statement("SET @balance = 0");` before your query. Your second query should still have access to it.

Comment: If you understand SQL, you will know that in the `from()` method you are attempting to select from 2 naturally joined tables, one an alias for a subselect of a variable. If it's required, this join should be made explicit in the code with the `join()` method, rather than relying on the comma join operator, which has been frowned upon for a long time now.

Comment: Also, using `$query->toSql()` on the old app might give you a better idea of the query you're working with.

Comment: @miken32 thanks for your answer, this was code on my Laravel 8.x version, and it was working as expected, upgrade to Laravel 10.x issues started, btw @aynber thanks for your comment `DB::statement("SET @balance = 0");` since this kind of worked for me, even without `->from(...)` statement, if there is a way to accept it as answer, let me know